# Where to use camelCase in Python according to PEP 8?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8, camelcasing, mixed-case

Recently I have started working on machine learning with Python, however I'm very new to this language. I know that ["Readability counts"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python), so I have been trying to get myself familiar with the
[PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) coding conventions. I know where to use
`joined_lower`, `StudlyCaps` and `ALL_CAPS` naming conventions, however I didn't quite get in which situations I can use the `camelCase`.

According to the PEP 8 guide:

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that’s already the
> prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
> compatibility.

but this statement isn't saying much to me. What does it mean by "prevailing style"? What could be an applicable case that would require this backward compatibility?

I couldn't find a single example on the web that used naming style to conform to pre-existing conventions.

Comment: "Prevailing style" means the one that's already in use. It's already given you an applicable example, _in the quote you've included_: [`threading.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/threading.py) (note these `mixedCase` names are deprecated from Python 3.10 per https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: This is probably the first question I've seen in months that is clear, useful and shows research effort so kudos to you

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't know that the "threading.py" file was referring to a code in the Python documents. I couldn't find that link in the PEP8 guide, so I was wondering what that was. Now, I get it, thank you.